# SSRS expression- Filter that does not eliminate "null" fields in report

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-tablix

**The Report Goal:** To display projects that are tagged with a specific status id and any project that has a "null" value in the field value, PJ_Project_Tags.

Fields!PJ_Project_Tags.Value is an integer and can have a value of 0 - 11.  Whenever I create a filter in the query, "is none of (5,6,8,9,10,11)" it eliminates projects with these numbers as well as projects with a null value for that field.  I get the same results if I create a query filter for PJ_Project_Tags "is any of (0,1,2,3,4,7).

**Things I have tried**
I created a calculated field in the dataset for PJ_Project_TagNULL to = 0 using the following expression =IIF(Fields!PJ_Project_Tags.Value=Nothing,0, Fields!PJ_Project_Tags.Value.  This resulted in a new column with all projects with a null value now having a value of "0."
I can do a filter that shows <= 4 to provide those projects but I am unsure how to create an expression to add in projects that are tagged with a 7.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the issue by doing the following:
Created a calculated field in the dataset to apply the value of 0 to any "null" PJ_Project_Tag Fields.
Added a filter to the Tablix with the following conditions
=Fields!PJ_ProjectTagNull.Value= 0 or Fields!PJ_Project_Tags.Value<=4 or Fields!PJ_Project_Tags.Value = 7.  The filter type is a Boolean, Operator is =, and Value is "True".

If anyone else has an easier way to do this, please let me know.  I appreciate learning from this community!